# Optimize nested loop

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I'm having a memory issue with my application with a nested for loop and I can't figure out how to improve it. I've tried using linq, but I guess that internally it's the same, because the memory leaks still is there.

**EDIT:** As I've been requested, I'll provide more information about my problem.

I've got all of my customers (about 400.000) indexed in a Lucene document store. Each customer can be present in more than one agency, exiting some of them than can be in 200-300 agencies.

I need to retrieve all of my customers from the 'global' customer index and build a separate index for each agency, only containing the customers it can see. There are some business rules and security rules that need to be applied to each agency index, so right now, I can't afford to maintain a single customer index for all my agencies.

My process looks like this:

```
int numDocuments = 400000;

// Get a Lucene Index Searcher from an Index Factory
IndexSearcher searcher = SearcherFactory.Instance.GetSearcher(Enums.CUSTOMER);

// Builds a query that gets everything in the index
Query query = QueryHelper.GetEverythingQuery();
Filter filter = new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(query));

// Sorts by Agency Id
SortField sortField = new SortField("AgencyId, SortField.LONG);
Sort sort = new Sort(sortField);

TopDocs documents = searcher.Search(query, filter, numDocuments, sort);

for (int i = 0; i < numDocuments; i++)
{
     Document document = searcher.Doc(documents.scoreDocs[i].doc);

     // Builds a customer object from the lucene document
     Customer customer = new Customer(document);

     // If this nested loop is removed, the memory doesn't grow
     foreach(Agency agency in customer.Agencies)
     {
          // Gets a writer from a factory for the agency id.
          IndexWriter writer = WriterFactory.Instance.GetWriter(agency.Id);

          // Builds an agency-specific document from the customer
          Document customerDocument = customer.GetAgencyDocument(agency.Id);

          // Adds the document to the agency's lucene index
          writer.AddDocument(customerDocument);
     }
}
```

**EDIT:** The solution

The problem was I wasn't reusing the instances of the "Document" object in the inner loop, and that caused an indecent grow of memory usage of my service. Just reusing a single instance of Document for the full process solved my problem.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: it really depends on what you are doing, this code by itself isn't leaky.

Comment: There's a difference between "using a lot of memory" and "a memory leak."

Comment: You have simplified it too much.

Comment: If the problem is that these lists are just "too big" and the nesting is a major performance hit... Does the inner loop do anything Customer-specific?  That is, can you logically loop through all of the Customers and _then_ loop through all of the Agencies and still accomplish the same task?  That would make the execution closer to `O(2x)` instead of `O(x^2)`.

Comment: I can have 400000 customers and each customer can be in 300 agencies. With this numbers, only the nested loop makes the memory usage grow constanly from the customer 90000 on.

Comment: If you have a list of 400k customers, their memory is going to hang around. If you then retrieve the entire list of agencies per customer, you're not going to avoid increasing memory usage as long as the customers remain in memory.

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler?  What you're considering a memory leak may be garbage collection.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2010/08/27/10055187.aspx) for a list of GC-related performance monitors.  Also, see if a Release build uses the same amount of memory.  Debug builds force objects to be around longer (so you can debug them).

Comment: What i believe to be happening here is: You have too much object creation inside the loops. If at all possible do no use the new() keyword inside the loops. Initialize objects that are reusable across the loops and pass them data to work on. DO not construct new objects inside that many loops because garbage collection will become a serios problem and the garbage collector may not be able to keep up with you.

Comment: This question is far too vague to survive here on Stack Overflow. Please fill in some of the blanks so that the answer is actually an answer, and not just a random shot in the dark that just happened to hit the target. Otherwise it will be closed as not-constructive or too-localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should re-use your `Document` and `Field` instances that you pass to `IndexWriter.AddDocument()` to minimize memory usage and relieve pressure on the garbage collector.

> • Re-use Document and Field instances As of Lucene 2.3 there are new
>   setValue(...) methods that allow you to change the value of a Field.
>   This allows you to re-use a single Field instance across many added
>   documents, which can save substantial GC cost. It's best to create a
>   single Document instance, then add multiple Field instances to it, but
>   hold onto these Field instances and re-use them by changing their
>   values for each added document. For example you might have an idField,
>   bodyField, nameField, storedField1, etc. After the document is added,
>   you then directly change the Field values (idField.setValue(...),
>   etc), and then re-add your Document instance.
>
> Note that you cannot re-use a single Field instance within a Document,
>   and, you should not change a Field's value until the Document
>   containing that Field has been added to the index.

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed

Answer (score 4):

What I believe to be happening here is:

You have too much object creation inside the loops. If at all possible do no use the new() keyword inside the loops. Initialize objects that are reusable across the loops and pass them data to work on. DO not construct new objects inside that many loops because garbage collection will become a serious problem and the garbage collector may not be able to keep up with you, and will defer collection.

The first thing you can do to try if this is true, try to force garbage collection every X loops and wait for pending finalizers. If this brings memory down you know that this is the problem. And solving it is easy: just do not create new instances every loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The key may be how you are initializing `customers`  and `customer.Agencies`. If you can, rather than returning a type of `List`, make  the return types `IEnumerable<Customer>` and `IEnumerable<Agency>`. This may allow deferred execution to happen, which should consume less memory, but may make the operation take longer.

Another option would be to run the code in batches, so use your code above, but populate `List<Customer> customers` in batches of, e.g., 10,000 at a time.

Comment: I wouldn't go for IEnumerable with 400000 customers

Comment: @memetolsen I guess that depends on the data source - with SQL it could definitely be an issue.

Comment: The data source is a Lucene index. Any queries to database are done for loading the customer list (with the agency list in each customer included)

Answer (score 1):

As @RedFilter said, try using IEnumerable along with the yield statement.

This may help:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx

http://www.alteridem.net/2007/08/22/the-yield-statement-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

Looping through a list in memory that is allready loaded in memory, you do not change the amount of memory that the list is using.

It must be something that you are doing to the items in the list that is causing the memory usage.

You need to look at what you are trying to achieve and redesign your program to not have all data in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to reduce the memory usage, then the basic answer is to break it up.

So get all the customers for one agency into a CustomersForAgency collection,then process just that.

Clearing or letting the CustomersForAgency collection got out of scope, will take all those customers and (optionally that agency) out of scope allowing .net to reuse the memory.

That's assuming of course that teh bulk of the memory allocation is for Customers, and not other persistent instances used for processing, you simplified out.

Comment: That's something I tried before, but a customer can be present in more than an agency. That means that if I iterate over the agencies, a customer is queried from the data source once for every agency.

Comment: That was one way to break the job up, bound to be more. You are going for a brute force approach at the moment, optimisation requires a deep knowledge of the requirement and the implementation. That's you. Two ways to go start with what you know, attack it, see what happens, or lateral thinking leads to a cunning plan. The latter might be possible, but if you are living this code, you need to "sleep on it", do something else for a bit. Often cunning plans arise from not thinking too hard about it.